# How to convert PDF to PDF/A using free and open source library?

Tags: java, kotlin, pdfbox, pdfa

How to convert PDF to PDF/A using free and open source library?

This is my code which convert word to pdf, I want to generate PDFA format pdf (A-4 standard is preferrable)

code:

````
@GetMapping(value = ["/generate-pdf"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE])
    fun generatePdf(): ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> {
        // Load the Word template
        val initialFile = File("src/main/resources/template.docx")
        val templateFile = FileInputStream(initialFile)
        val document = XWPFDocument(templateFile)

        // Modify the document as needed
        val paragraphs: List<XWPFParagraph> = document.paragraphs
        for (paragraph in paragraphs) {
            val runs: List<XWPFRun> = paragraph.runs
            for (run in runs) {
                val text = run.getText(0)
                if (text != null) {
                    val replacedText = text.replace("{{name}}", "John Doe").replace("{{product}}", "Sample Product")
                    run.setText(replacedText, 0)
                }
            }
        }
        val out: OutputStream = FileOutputStream("outputfile.pdf")
        val options: PdfOptions? = null
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options)

        val file = FileSystemResource("outputfile.pdf")

        val responseHeaders = HttpHeaders()
        responseHeaders.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF
        responseHeaders.contentLength = file.contentLength()
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=outputfile.pdf")

        // Load the converted PDF
        val pdfFile = File("outputfile.pdf")
        val pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(file)

    }```


How can i convert from PDF to PDF/A 
I want free and open source library. Spire pdf i have seen. it adds some warning text on top. 

Other IText and aspose are paid and come with some licence
````

Comment: PDFBox can't do it, there are so many flaws in PDFs in the wild. You'll need a commercial product, unless the PDFs are all of the same kind and you can correct the flaws easily (e.g. just set the XMP and the OutputIntent). Use PDFBox Preflight or VeraPDF to check what flaws you have in your PDFs.